# How to implement a paint-update loop?

Tags: android

I want to create a paint and update loop in android for game animation on a canvas but I am having trouble as I can't seem to get the threading to work appropriately. It seems to crash almost immediately. Here is what I have tried:

```
    // Create the thread supplying it with the runnable object
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);

    // Start the thread in oncreate()
    thread.start();


    class runner implements Runnable {
    // This method is called when the thread runs
    long wait = 1000;

    public void run() {

    update();
    }

    public void update()
    {
        try{
          Thread.currentThread();
            //do what you want to do before sleeping
          Thread.sleep(wait);//sleep for 1000 ms
          //do what you want to do after sleeping
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){
        //If this thread was interrupted by another thread 
        }

        run();
    }
}
```

Also when I drop the wait down lower it crashes faster.

Is there a more appropriate way to approach this?

Changed to this:

```
class runner implements Runnable {
// This method is called when the thread runs
long wait = 10;
boolean blocked = false;

public void run() {

    if(!blocked){
        blocked = true;
        paint();
    }
}


public void paint()
{

    update();
}


public void update()
{
    try{
      Thread.currentThread();
        //do what you want to do before sleeping
      Thread.sleep(wait);//sleep for 1000 ms
      //do what you want to do after sleeping
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ie){
    //If this thread was interrupted by another thread 
    }

    paint();
}
```

}

This results in the same error... :/

Comment: If you are using eclipse, open the ddms or logcat window.  If you aren't using eclipse, run adb logcat (or adb.exe logcat on windows) from the command line.  adb is located in the tools folder.

Comment: execute `adb logcat` from a command line. adb utility is inside the tools folder of the SDK. Or, you can open the LogCat view from Eclipse, if that's your IDE.

Comment: 09-08 16:10:38.146: INFO/dalvikvm(927): Stack overflow, expanding (0x42384200 to 0x42384000)
09-08 16:10:38.146: INFO/dalvikvm(927): Shrank stack (to 0x42384200, curFrame is 0x42385fe8)
09-08 16:10:38.156: WARN/dalvikvm(927): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your 'loop'.

You should NOT call run manually on an already started thread.

```
public void run()
{
  while (true)
  {
    // do whatever
    Thread.sleep(wait);
  }
}
```

I would not actually use the above either, I'd use a Timer or Android equivalent. You should get the concept from this though.

Answer (score 4):

Well the first thing I notice is that run calls update and update calls run.  This is going to cause a NO PUN INTENDED Stack Overflow.  They call each other until the stacks fills up.  Then it should crash.